Adding new chart series but excluding them from the legend
VBA. I'm trying to edit a chart by adding multiple new series to indicate when certain phases begin at certain times. I've done this by writing code that creates series using x values of the date i.e. (10/1/24 to 10/1/24) and y values -1000 to 1000 to create a vertical line. However I was wondering if there was a way to exclude these new series from the legend, as the legend gets too large, and the plot is running slowly - causing difficulties with manually deleting legend entries.
I'm very new to VBA and coding in general - any tips or suggestions are welcome. Thank you!!
Sub Plottest()

With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
.MinimumScale = 45566
.MajorUnit = 30.5
.MaximumScale = 45748
End With


With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.Name = "='Connection Data'!B2"
.XValues = "='Connection Data'!A2:A3"
.Values = "='Connection Data'!C2:C3"
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.Name = "='Connection Data'!B4"
.XValues = "='Connection Data'!A4:A5"
.Values = "='Connection Data'!C4:C5"
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.Name = "='Connection Data'!B6"
.XValues = "='Connection Data'!A6:A7"
.Values = "='Connection Data'!C6:C7"
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.Name = "='Connection Data'!B8"
.XValues = "='Connection Data'!A8:A9"
.Values = "='Connection Data'!C8:C9"
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

End Sub 


Something like this maybe: ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(x).Delete (where x is the index of the legend entry for the series)
